# How to override a plugin of Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need help overriding Visual Composer plugin of Wordpress.

My intention is to change the default value of the Single Image element.

I'm working in the child theme and I created a "duplicated" `.php` file (the one I want to modify), but the theme doesn't read it. I even tried adding a function in the plugin original file (`shortcode_vc_single_page`), and nothing changed.

The function that I tried is:

```
if( !function_exists('vc_single_image_func')){

    / * _(((the rest of the .php)))_ */

}
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: which theme and plugin are those?

Comment: The theme is: lpd-themes 456Industry, and the pugin is: WPBakery Visual Composer

Comment: Have to say that if you cannot find a suitable hook to modify the plugin behaviour and achieve your goal, then the plugin is not designed to work your way. Of course you can do thing like duplicate the plugin and modify it or create subclasses of the plugin's class and extend its function, etc. However, all of these should be considered bad practices and should be avoided, since there are no way to maintain these changes and keep them align with plugin's update in the future. If plugin is open-source, may be you can make a pull request for the feature you want.

Comment: The thing is that I used the same hook with other file of the plugin and worked perfectly, so I don't understand why with this one is different.